# Shall we keep asking our child to share her food?

Tags: sharing

Our girl is almost 2 years old. Whenever she asks for snack from us, we will give it to her share and an additional share for her to give to mother / father (myself) / her friends / other adults.

Intuitively, I am hoping my daughter will learn to share this way, but there is no proof.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I suspect that this will be considered an opinion based question, and as such is not really answerable in this forum.

Comment: @pojo-guy There could be research on that topic, though.

Comment: This is rather unclear, especially since there is no follow up on the question in the title - how often do you ask her, how does she react? Doyou really want to know whether you should keep asking her, or is your question how to teach her to share with others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a parent whose child has a peanut allergy, please don't encourage your child to share food.

In our primary school, children are taught explicitly not to share food due to the prevalence of food allergies, our son has always been told not to share food or accept food and still it happens. For some children, this is extremely dangerous.

In our kindergarten, there was a lengthy list of food allergies in the current cohort - I didn't event know you could be allergic to bananas!

Answer (score 3):

It would be okay to teach a child, however not a 2 years old, to share foods, in case you might be living in underdeveloped places with food issues, which does not seem to be the case for you.

Sharing food is an old-fashioned diminishing cultural practice, which is not really an educational concern to be thought to a child of such age. Many cultures are not really fan of such sharings and it is also considered dangerous as dave points out.